# Injective module and Noetherian ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

In the book **Abstract Algebra** of **J.Antoine Grillet** there is a theorem as follows:

> A ring $R$ is left Noetherian if and only if every direct sum of
>   injective left R-modules is injective

The Noetherian property is the core of the proof of this theorem in the book. However, I also know a proposition that says every direct product of injective modules is injective. In the finite case, the direct product and direct sum are the same, so the direct sum of injective modules is also injective.

So we do not need the Noetherian property anymore. Am I wrong?

Please explain for me. Thanks.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you've basically answered  it yourself: a finite direct sum of injective modules over an arbitrary ring is injective, but that need not be the case for an infinite direct sum.

Comment: Dear @MartinWanvik Are infinite direct sum and infinite direct product the same ?

Comment: No, they're not (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules).

Comment: @MartinWanvik : Thanks you very much !

Comment: Could you give me an example of an injective sum but not injective?

Comment: Nobody could give you such an example! If the direct sum of some modules is injective, then each module is injective.

Comment: @navigetor23 You misunderstood me. Please read the above comments.

Comment: @msnaber It is obvious that my comment is refering to Miss Independent question.

Answer (score 1):

To shore up this question, the point is that infinite direct products are very different from infinite direct sums.

It is true that arbitrary products of injective modules are injective, and that a finite direct sum of injective modules is also a finite direct product and so is injective, but neither of these facts proves that an arbitrary (meaning possibly infinite) direct sum of injectives in injective.

To learn more about the proof that this is equivalent to Noetherianness of the ring, see this post: [Projective and injective modules; direct sums and products](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/173702/29335).